# Error: expected conv3d_1_input to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (10, 224, 224, 3)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to train a Neural Network on a dataset for liveness anti-spoofing. I have some videos in two folders named `genuine` and `fake`. I have extracted 10 frames of each video and saved them in two folders with aforementioned names under a new directory `tarining`.

```
--/training/
----/genuine/   #containes 10frame*300videos=3000images
----/fake/   #containes 10frame*800videos=8000images
```

I designed the following 3D Convent using Keras as my first try, but after running it, it throws the following exception:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras import Model, optimizers, activations, losses, regularizers, backend, Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, MaxPooling3D, AveragePooling3D, Conv3D, Input, Flatten, BatchNormalization

BATCH_SIZE = 10
TARGET_SIZE = (224, 224)

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255,
                                   data_format='channels_last',
                                   validation_split=0.2,
                                   shear_range=0.0,
                                   zoom_range=0,
                                   horizontal_flip=False,
                                   featurewise_center=False,
                                   featurewise_std_normalization=False,
                                   width_shift_range=False,
                                   height_shift_range=False)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory("./training/",
                                                    target_size=TARGET_SIZE,
                                                    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                                    class_mode='binary',
                                                    shuffle=False,
                                                    subset='training')

validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory("./training/",
                                                    target_size=TARGET_SIZE,
                                                    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                                    class_mode='binary',
                                                    shuffle=False,
                                                    subset='validation')

SHAPE = (10, 224, 224, 3)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv3D(filters=128, kernel_size=(1, 3, 3), data_format='channels_last', activation='relu', input_shape=(10, 224, 224, 3)))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(data_format='channels_last', pool_size=(1, 2, 2)))
model.add(Conv3D(filters=64, kernel_size=(2, 3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1, 2, 2)))
model.add(Conv3D(filters=32, kernel_size=(2, 3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv3D(filters=32, kernel_size=(2, 3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1, 2, 2)))
model.add(Conv3D(filters=16, kernel_size=(2, 3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv3D(filters=16, kernel_size=(2, 3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(AveragePooling3D())
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.adam(), loss=losses.binary_crossentropy, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=train_generator.samples/train_generator.batch_size, epochs=5, validation_data=validation_generator, validation_steps=validation_generator.samples/validation_generator.batch_size)
model.save('3d.h5')
```

Here is the Error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv3d_1_input to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (10, 224, 224, 3)
```

And this is the output of `model.summary()`

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv3d_1 (Conv3D)            (None, 10, 222, 222, 128) 3584      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling3d_1 (MaxPooling3 (None, 10, 111, 111, 128) 0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv3d_2 (Conv3D)            (None, 9, 109, 109, 64)   147520    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling3d_2 (MaxPooling3 (None, 9, 54, 54, 64)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv3d_3 (Conv3D)            (None, 8, 52, 52, 32)     36896     
_________________________________________________________________
conv3d_4 (Conv3D)            (None, 7, 50, 50, 32)     18464     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling3d_3 (MaxPooling3 (None, 7, 25, 25, 32)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv3d_5 (Conv3D)            (None, 6, 23, 23, 16)     9232      
_________________________________________________________________
conv3d_6 (Conv3D)            (None, 5, 21, 21, 16)     4624      
_________________________________________________________________
average_pooling3d_1 (Average (None, 2, 10, 10, 16)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 2, 10, 10, 16)     64        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 2, 10, 10, 32)     544       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 2, 10, 10, 1)      33        
=================================================================
Total params: 220,961
Trainable params: 220,929
Non-trainable params: 32
__________________________________________________________
```

I'd appreciate any help to fix the exception. By the way, I'm using TensorFlow as backend if it helps to solve the problem.

Comment: Doesn't the error say it all? `conv3d_1` expects a `(None, 10, 222, 222, 128)` input. But you're trying to feed a `10, 224, 224, 3` input. If you want to feed in a single data point, you will need to reshape your data (e.g. `np.expand_dims(input, 0))` so that it is `[1, 10, 222, 222, 128]` size.

Comment: @thushv89 Why would it be (None, 10, 222, 222, 128)? as Doc says the first layer Conv3D takes input as:
"When using this layer as the first layer in a model, provide the keyword argument input_shape (tuple of integers, does not include the batch axis), e.g. input_shape=(128, 128, 128, 1) for 128x128x128 volumes with a single channel, in data_format="channels_last"."

which is of the format (frames, height, width, channels) for a video.
am I wrong?

Comment: How can I reshape the data when using ImageDataGenerator and flow_from_directory? @thushv89

Comment: @Mohommad I think you misunderstood. While setting up the model that's the way to do (i.e. ignore the batch dimension). But at the time of passing data, you can't ignore the batch dimension. Actual data needs to have that dimension.

Comment: Re reshaping data, did you set the batch size ? `datagen.flow_from_directory(…, batch_size=32, ...)`

Comment: @thushv89 Oh I see ... thanks for correcting me. yes the batch_size is already set.

Comment: Can you check the shape of a batch of data returned by your generator by running `train_generator.__getitem__()` and checking `.shape` on the output?

Comment: @thushv89 it's (10, 224, 224, 3)

Comment: That's weird, because your `batch_size` is 64. Seems your generator hasn't used that.

Comment: @thushv89 i'm sorry i've just changed the batch size in my local. i changed from 64 to 10.

Comment: Alright so the problem is that I don't think the `imagedatagenerator` is probably not the best method to handle video data [issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11977). Because I don't think you can add that missing batch dimension easily. So you might want to manipulate your data by taking batches using `__getitem__()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @thushv89 mentioned in the comments Keras has no build-in video generator which causes a lot of problems for those who will work with big video datasets. Therefore, I wrote a simple VideoDataGenerator which works almost as simple as ImageDataGenerator. The script could be found [here on my github](https://github.com/Msiavashi/VideoDataGenerator) in case someone needs it in the future.